# A link to the server could not be established

Tags: php, database

A very simple insert function, and yet. It gives some nasty errors...

Like:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user '***.'@'***.one.com' (using password: NO) in /customers/***.be/***.be/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 24 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /customers/***.be/***.be/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 24
```

And this is the code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $naam = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $kind1 = $_POST['kind1'];
    $kind2 = $_POST['kind2'];
    $kind3 = $_POST['kind3'];
    $kind4 = $_POST['kind4'];
    $kind5 = $_POST['kind5'];
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

        if ($captcha == 2){
            if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['kind1'])) {
                    $insert = "INSERT INTO belastingen (ouder, email, kind1, kind2, kind3, kind4, kind5) VALUES (
                            '".$naam."',
                            '".$email."',
                            '".$kind1."',
                            '".$kind2."',
                            '".$kind3."',
                            '".$kind4."',
                            '".$kind5."')";
                if (!mysql_query($insert)) {
                    echo "<div class=\"feedback\">query invoeren faalt</div>";
                } else { 
                    echo "<div class=\"feedback\">Uw registratie werd goed geregistreerd</div>";
                }


                }    else {
                echo "<div class=\"feedback\">falen, niveau 2</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"feedback\">captcha probleem</div>";
        }
    }   
?>
```

And don't worry about the MySQL-injection. Adding as we speak.
Any thought about the error?
And yes I'm sure the data for connection to the database are correct.

**UPDATE 1**
This is my `inc.php`-file, included on top of the index.php file.

```
<?php
  define('MYSQL_HOST',  '***.be.mysql');
  define('MYSQL_DB',    '***');
  define('MYSQL_USER',  '***');
  define('MYSQL_PASSW', '***');

  require_once 'classes/dbconnections.php';
  require_once 'classes/btw.php';
  $_DB = new DBConnection(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSW);
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**
This is my `dbconnections.php`-file

```
<?php

class DBConnection {

  public  $host;
  public  $db;
  public  $user;
  public  $password;

  private $_connection;

  public function __construct($host = null, $db = null, $user = null, $password = null) {
    $this->host     = $host;
    $this->db       = $db;
    $this->user     = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->connect();
  }

  private function connect(){
    $this->_connection = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
    if(!$this->_connection) {
      die("An error occured---- while connecting to the database: ".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error());
    } else{
      $selected = mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->_connection);
      if(!$selected) {
        die("An error occured while connecting to the database: ".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error());
      }
    } 
  }

  public function listing($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $return[] = $row;
    }
    return $return;
  }

  public function select($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
  }

  public function insert($sql) {
    mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection);
  }

  public function delete($sql) {
    mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection);
  }

  public function escape($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
  }

}

?>
```

**UPDATE 3**
The error I get when replacing the thins suggested below

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _DB in /customers/***/***/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 13 Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /customers/***/***/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 13
```

Comment: Do you properly initialize a mysql connection using `mysql_connect` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) passing a password? The error seems to indicate no password was passed, or a connection was not found to use for the query. If you have a connection link identifier, pass it as the second parameter of `mysql_query`

Comment: I include a `inc.php`file where the connection is made if that's what you mean?

Comment: Do you have an `include 'inc.php'` in the file the above snippet is from? Any chance you can paste the `inc.php` code while ensuring you obfuscate any passwords or other path information?

Comment: The error is coming from that inc.php if that is where the connection is made. not in this piece of code. And it is either you'r db login is incorrect, or insufficient login privileges to the db.

Comment: @robx I thought so at first too, but the error snippet says a server could not be established for the `mysql_query` call in his code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I included my `inc.php` file in the original code... It' strange, cause almost the same code worked just fine on another website. Maybe it's my hoster?

Comment: Your `DBConnection` doesn't supply password to MySQL server, so it responds with `Access denied for user` bla bla `(using password: **NO**)`

Comment: But it does `define('MYSQL_PASSW', '***');` no?

Comment: It might be something to do with the 'dbconnections' class you are using, and I am not sure how this particular class works (could be anything, really, I am assuming you defined it yourself?).

Comment: Yes, i do. If you like, I can post it as well...

Comment: Yes, that would help. I am not sure how the class defines the connection, and then you may have to reference it like `$_DB->connection` or something like `mysql_query($insert, $DB->connection)`.

Comment: and your class DBConnection does what? the root is where you are doing mysql_connect(host,user,pass)

Comment: I added the `dbconnection.php` file. Does it have to be in the root (cause it's not...)

Comment: So it looks like rather than `mysql_query($insert)`, you should use `$_DB->insert($insert)`. Give that a shot and see if it works. (EDIT: I was referencing the 'index.php' code, btw. realized it may have been confusing)

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But for some reason there is a new error `Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in` strange. It looks like the `inc.php`-file isn't included after all. Or I'm a mistaken? (EDIT: on the `index.php` is no such query... You do mean replace `if (!mysql_query($insert))` with `if (!$_DB->insert($insert))` right?

Comment: Can you check to make sure the `inc.php` file is included in the `index.php` file (are you saying you aren't sure if it is?). And that is the replacement I meant.

Comment: Ok, just tested. The `inc.php` file is included in the `index.php` file. No doubt about it. But it seems the connection to the `dbconnections.php` is failing... (although, it's included in de `index.php`-file as well, for sure.)

Comment: just noticed something...and you're gonna hate me :)...but can you post the 'btw.php' class as well? The original error references that file too. Are you still getting the "Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in" error (and, if so, can you please post the full error also)?

Comment: Ok, I don't mind posting, as long as you don't mind reading my crappy code :) But the `btw.php` file you're aiming for, is already posted. It's the first one.

Comment: aha! Ok, so don't require 'db.inc' in 'btw.php'. And, in db.inc, try putting `require_once 'classes/btw.php';` after the $_DB=.... in `db.inc` instead of before it.

Comment: Eum, not sure what you mean with your first sentense... And in `inc.php` is `btw` stated last and in `dbconnections.php` there is nothing included... (EDIT: nevermind, got your idea. Let me see)

Comment: Still the `Undefined variale....` stuff

Comment: I think the problem is that in db.inc, the btw.php file is included before the $_DB variable is even created, thus any references in btw.php for $_DB return the error you posted in reply to @steve (this comment is just kind of a summary of what the steps I last wrote were trying to solve)

Comment: sorry to keep tugging at you in different directions, but I am helping you by going through things the way I would if it was my code. That said, try changing things up so that `db.inc` is required in `btw.php`; `btw.php` is required in `index.php` rather than `db.inc`; and 'btw.php` is not required in `db.inc`. From reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, I think this might have to do with scope

Comment: @William - I think you are right, `$_DB = new DBConnection ...` needs to be moved above the btw.inc include line.

Comment: Agreed. If your btw file is the very first set of code on this post, then you should create your db connection before including btw since btw wants to use query.

Comment: @William, your last comment was my answer! Hoera :) problem was indeed with db.inc! Thanks!! (If you answer the question, I can accept is)

Comment: @Michiel, good to hear! Does it make sense why the solution worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments on your question, try changing things up so that inc.php is required in btw.php; btw.php is required in index.php rather than inc.php; and 'btw.php` is not required in inc.php. From reading php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, I think this might have to do with scope.

EDIT:

First off, the setup you have creates a custom database object class (`DBConnection`) which is used to interface with the database and execute queries. When you used `mysql_query` by itself, it did not have a database connection identifier from which to execute the query, since the DBConnection object abstracts that functionality in object methods. That is why you needed to use `if (!$_DB->insert($insert))`.

Secondly, and I'm not 100% on this, but essentially core the problem seems to have to do with the code in `btw.php` not "seeing" the database setup code. This could have been because of two things. First, the `$_DB` variable was defined *after* the `btw.php` code was required, and as a result, when the PHP interpreter parsed `btw.php`, `$_DB` had not yet been defined. The order if the requires and the database object definition matter. Secondly, and this is where I am a bit unsure, but I think there is a variable scope/access issue when requiring `btw.php` from within `inc.php` (where `$_DB` is defined) rather than requiring the database setup within `btw.php`. In other words, you had the code that uses the database object required in the script that defines it, rather than the database setup script (including the database object declaration) required within the code that uses it.

I hope that makes sense, please let me know if it is still confusing. I tend to have a problem explaining things concisely.

Comment: In addition to the comments, I does make sense, but I don't get it all the way. Care to explain a bit more? :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you are using your DBConnection class to make the query. Of course, it's in that class that the connection is made. By calling mysql_query() directly, PHP is using localhost, the web server account and no password when attempting the query. So you need to do something like

```
if($_DB->insert($insert) > 0)
{
     ...
```

Comment: Replace the line `if (!mysql_query($insert)) {` in your first code snipped with what I've posted.

Comment: Like I said, error :(   `Notice: Undefined variable: _DB in /customers/***.be/***.be/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 13 Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /customers/***.be/***.be/httpd.www/belastingen/classes/btw.php on line 13`

Comment: Can you check that you have `$_DB` and not `_DB`. The error suggests you are missing the dollar sign, which is required for all variables in PHP.

Comment: @Steve: As far as I can tell from a quick google search of "php undefined variable", undefined variable messages seem to exclude the dollar sign here (I thought the same thing you did at first)

Comment: @William. Huh, never knew that. Well I would then think that the inc.php and dbconnections.php are not being included in btw.php. Michiel, can you confirm this? You noted that the files were included in index.php, but the error is on btw.php. You'll have to include the files there as well.

Answer (score -2):

just make sure the sql query is correct
this error can happen when mixup mixedup mysql  and mysql query in files associated with this action or may be the erroe will be that of the parameter supplied for mysqliquery